# WiX Reboot target machine if installation fails

Tags: wix, windows-installer, restart

Is it possible to have the WiX installer reboot the target machine if the installation fails *for any reason*?

This is a requirement that I have.

I'm using a Bootstrapper.  After the initial installation all updates will be done automatically.  If the installation fails, I need to:

- send appropriate logs (done)
- rollback to a good state (done), and
- reboot the target machine

I restart the target machine after a successful installation, but I don't know how to restart the machine if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to each package in the chain.  The first will allow it to complete without reboot if it was successful, the second will force it to reboot on any other exit code.

```
<ExePackage Id="MyExe" SourceFile="MySource.exe">
   <ExitCode Behavior="success" Value="0" />
   <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>
</ExePackage>
```

It sounds like you're already rebooting after a successful installation, so you might just want to remove the Value="0", so it forces a reboot for any exit code.